# Git Repo with submodules tracking different branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

Here is my scenario:

Master-branch:

```
git main repo [branch:master]
-> submodule
---> subMod_A [branch:alfa tracking origin/alfa]
```

Hotel-branch

```
git main repo [branch:hotel]
-> submodule
---> subMod_A [branch:beta trakcking origin/beta]
```

**Edit 1 [clarification]:**

> Changing from ***Master*** to ***Hotel*** branch, also changes the submodule
> branch from ***alfa*** to ***beta*** branch. This is intended.
>
> We do this because we have electronics with minor variations in
> implementation.

When I switch between *Master* and *Hotel*, the submodule HEAD is always detached.
I've already tried with submodule.subMod_A.update=rebase/merge with the same result.

**Edit 2:**

> ```
> git submodule status
> ```
>
> The output confirms that it is on the new branch with the correct commit id. But I still have to "reattach" it
> by hand with checking out the branch again

What would be the best/standard way of achieving this?

Best regards
framet

Comment: That isn't the way submodules are intended to be used, I think.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+detached+HEAD

Comment: I've seen those question. I've tested it and it is working when root repo changes the branch but the submodule branch is the same. In my particular case changing the main repo branch should also switch the submodule branch to another branch. I could not get it to work. Therfor I aksed this specific question.